# Filter json render in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the best way if i would like to only return :id and :name fields in JSON

So far i have:

```
format.json { render :json => @contacts.map(&:attributes) , :only => ["id"]}
```

But the "name" attribute does not work in the :only section, since it is not a column in the database (it is defined in the model as firstname + lastname)

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can pass `:methods` to to_json / as_json

```
format.json do
  render :json => @contacts.map { |contact| contact.as_json(:only => :id, :methods => :name) }
end
```

Alternatively you can just build up a hash manually

```
format.json do
  render :json => @contacts.map { |contact| {:id => contact.id, :name => contact.name} }
end
```

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Comment: We updated our comment at the same time. Now i get: [{"contact":{"name":"Executor From_wizard","id":null}}] but i need [{"name":"Executor From_wizard","id":"1"}]

Comment: Try setting this first `ActiveModel::Base.include_root_in_json = false`

Comment: no way to use the .map(&:attributes) somewhere to only show attributes? Not sure i want to change the default behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: ok found a way that works: 
render :json => @contacts.map { |contact| {:id => contact.id, :name => contact.name} }
Thanks for the help. Please edit your answer with this info, i'll set it as good answer.

Answer (score 35):

Rails 3 supports following filter options. as simple as is

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @contacts, :only => [:id, :name] }
end
```

Comment: actually since name is a method i believe it will be  render json: @contacts, only: [:id], methods: [:name]