# filtering the json render in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

so i have this piece of code:

```
 render :json => { :objects => @object.object_children }
```

This works. But What I only want are certain attributes only. I saw this: [filter json render in rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395620/filter-json-render-in-rails-3) and in it is this:

```
respond_to do |format|
format.json { render json: @objects.object_children, :only => [:id, :name] }
end
```

It works, but it returns data without a label, just like this:

```
id":null,"name":"foo"
```

I want the ":objects =>" label in it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine your original solution with the one you found:

```
render :json => { :objects => @object.object_children.as_json(:only => [:id, :name]) }
```

EDIT: Explanation

In your original solution you're adding the key `:objects =>` manually to the response.

```
render :json => @object.object_children
# vs
render :json => { :objects => @object.object_children }
```

So to add the key *and* filter the returned attributes you have to do the same but then call as_json (that's what Rails would do for simply returning the whole collection) manually with the `:only` option to apply the filter.

If you use the `respond_to` block depends on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

For advanced json serialization, check out [Active Model Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)