# How to remove attribute from object (Rails & Ajax)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am sending an object through ajax, using the following hash:

```
container = { "client" => client, "status" => "success"}
render :json => container.to_json
```

The `client` is an object with token and password.

I can't change the javascript, it asks for the response in this shape:

```
$.ajax({
  {...}
  },
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.status == "success") { ... < do things with data.client >
```

I was trying to use:

```
container = { "client" => client.to_json(:only => [ :id, :first_name, :last_name, :address, :phone]), "status" => "success"}
render :json => container.to_json
```

But so the second `.to_json` handle the first as a string and wraps it between quotes.

Could someone has some idea to help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5395620/877472), not certain yet. Check the second answer, it may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for reply Paul. I really tried to figure it out, but I couldn't.
I mean, I need a specific shape in the response. The response object, lets say, [data], must has:

data.client,
data.status

In this question it is doing like what I wrote above and that isn't working.

Comment: By now I am using a method that clear the object, but does't seem right for me. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `slice`?

```
container = { "client" => client.slice :id, :first_name, :last_name, :address, :phone }
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice